# Can we compute $ \mathbf{Pr}[x_{1} < X < x_{2}] $ if we know the cumulative distribution function $ F $?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume that we have a cumulative distribution function $ F $. How can we calculate the quantity $ \mathbf{Pr}[x_{1} < X < x_{2}] $?

I know the answer for $ \mathbf{Pr}[x_{1} < X \leq x_{2}] $, but I am not sure about $ \mathbf{Pr}[x_{1} < X < x_{2}] $.

Comment: Please reread your question before posting it. Are you looking for the probability in the title? Also, use LaTeX commands!

Comment: You are going to have to give us some more information here. For example, is $X$ a continuous or discrete random variable? In fact it would be good to explain what you mean by "the answer" for $x1".

Comment: Do you know what $P(x_2)$ is?

Comment: @n.c. Omitting a “please” in your comment *and* ending the comment with an exclamation mark seems slightly impolite due to my humanistic educational background.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe It was never my intention to be impolite. If the OP was offended by my comment, I want to apologize. I will take your suggestion into account for future comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether $X$ is discrete or continuos, in any case
$$P(x_1<X<x_2)=F(x_2)-F(x_1)-P(X=x_2).$$ 
You may want to draw a picture.

Comment: Your answer remains valid even if $ X $ is neither discrete nor continuous. :)

Comment: @Argument That's what it's made for: kiss (keep it simple and stupid).

Comment: I think it might be worthwhile to point out that $P(X = x_2) = F(x_2)-\lim_{x \uparrow x_2} F(x)$. (Since the question was phrased in terms of cdfs.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean that $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function for some continuous random variable with probability density function $f(x)$, where:

$$F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)\:du$$

You are trying to find the probability that $x$ lies between the values $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$. You therefore are looking to find the integral, $P(x_{1},x_{2})$, such that:

$$P(x_{1},x_{2}):=\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}f(x)\:dx$$

Note that due to the fundamental theorem of calculus we can write:

$$P(x_{1},x_{2})=\int_{-\infty}^{x_{2}}f(x)\:dx-\int_{-\infty}^{x_{1}}f(x)\:dx$$

Which due to our definition of $F(x)$ earlier is simply:

$$P(x_{1},x_{2})=F(x_{2})-F(x_{1})$$

I hope this helps

---

EDIT: Note that $\mathrm{Pr}(x_{1}\lt x \lt x_{2})=\mathrm{Pr}(x_{1}\lt x \leq x_{2})=\mathrm{Pr}(x_{1}\leq x\lt x_{2})=\mathrm{Pr}(x_{1}\leq x \leq x_{2})$ due to the continuous nature of the random variable and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: $X$ may be discrete as well.

Comment: $X$ may be discrete, but I was trying to give a reason for the answer and I chose to do it for a continuous variable. If I get time I may go back and edit my answer to include discrete variables :)

Comment: @Shaktal Your answer is simply wrong for discrete $X$.  Consider the number you get when throwing a dice once. You claim that $0=P(2<X<3)=F(3)-F(2)=3/6-2/6$ ...

Comment: @PardisPashakhanloo I  have strong doubts about that.

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I use the notation $p A = \mathbf{Pr}[X \in A]$.
Let $F$ be the cumulative distribution function, that is $F(\alpha) = p (-\infty,\alpha]$.

The relevant identities are $(a,b] = (-\infty,b] \setminus (-\infty, a]$ and
$(-\infty, a) = \cup_{n} (-\infty, a-\frac{1}{n}]$.

Combining gives $(a,b) = \cup_{n} (a, b-\frac{1}{n}]$.

The above shows that $p(a,b] = F(b)-F(a)$, as you already knew, and also
$p(a,b) = \lim_n F(b-\frac{1}{n}) - F(a)$. (Since $F$ is increasing and bounded above by 1, we know the limit exists.)

So, to restate, we have $p(a,b) = \lim_{t \uparrow b} F(t) - F(a)$.

It is possible to have $p(a,b) < p(a,b]$. For example, letting $F(\alpha) = \begin{cases} 0, & \alpha < 0 \\ 1, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Then $p(-1,0) = 0$, but $p(-1,1] = 1$.